# seaborn fails on databricks

Tags: python, seaborn

Simple code to create a histogram repeatedly fails. The issue is that I cannot change or reinstall versions. What can be done to fix?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random
import seaborn as sns

random.seed(2023)  # to create the same plot each time
x = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(100)]
y = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(100)]

df = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'value': x, 'name': 'x'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'value': y, 'name': 'y'})
])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(
    data=df, x='value', hue='name', multiple='dodge',
    bins=range(1, 110, 10), ax=ax
)

sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

the following code results in the following:

```
OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'mode.use_inf_as_null'"
```

Seaborn version: '0.11.2'

Comment: What library versions are you using?

Comment: this works for me `seaborn-0.13.0`. Which versions do you have ?

Comment: version '0.11.2'

Comment: Sadly there is not much you can do ; seaborn 0.11 is not compatible with pandas 2.x. Either you have to upgrade seaborn or to downgrade pandas ; I would suggest using a virtual environment if you are not willing/able to modify the regular python install.